# Chrome adds extra saturation/contrast to images

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser

As you can see in this image

[image]

, left half is from Edge and right half is from Chrome. Edge browser renders correctly, but Chrome adds what looks like extra contrast. It is especially visible in darker areas, like shadows.
Lossless images look better, and jpegs with higher compression are really bad with compression artefacts becoming very visible.

This started quite a few versions ago, I just did not realise it. I though it was re-compressed by the websites, until I compared it to another browser.

Tried resetting settings and reinstalling browser. What else can I do to fix this?

Comment: If anyone else is struggling with this, I kind of got to the root cause, but no solution. Apparently, Chrome applies monitor calibration profile on the images and if the image contains profile already, it applies it twice. Switching it to sRGB seems to be a workaround under chrome://flags/#force-color-profile